# AutoMapper - mapping doesn't work

Tags: c#, automapper

I want to map a simple collection of KeyValuePair objects to my custom class.
Unfortunatelly I only get an exception

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping.

Mapping types:
RuntimeType -> DictionaryType
System.RuntimeType -> AutoMapperTest.Program+DictionaryType

Destination path:
IEnumerable`1[0].Type.Type

Source value:
System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[AutoMapperTest.Program+DictionaryType,System.String]
```

Code in simplest form to reproduce this problem

```
class Program
{
    public enum DictionaryType
    {
        Type1,
        Type2
    }

    public class DictionariesListViewModels : BaseViewModel
    {
        public string Name { set; get; }
        public DictionaryType Type { set; get; }
    }

    public class BaseViewModel
    {
        public int Id { set; get; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap<
            KeyValuePair<DictionaryType, string>, DictionariesListViewModels>()
            .ConstructUsing(r =>
            {
                var keyValuePair = (KeyValuePair<DictionaryType, string>)r.SourceValue;
                return new DictionariesListViewModels
                {
                    Type = keyValuePair.Key,
                    Name = keyValuePair.Value
                };
            });

        List<KeyValuePair<DictionaryType, string>> collection =
            new List<KeyValuePair<DictionaryType, string>>
        {
            new KeyValuePair<DictionaryType, string>(DictionaryType.Type1, "Position1"),
            new KeyValuePair<DictionaryType, string>(DictionaryType.Type2, "Position2")
        };

        var mappedCollection = AutoMapper.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<DictionariesListViewModels>>(collection);


        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

I have other mapping created the same way (without enum) and they works, so it must be a problem, but how to workaround it? It must be something simple that I have problem to note.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ConstructUsing` only instructs AutoMapper how to *construct* the destination type. It will continue to attempt to map each property after constructing an instance of the destination type.

What you want instead is `ConvertUsing` which tells AutoMapper that you want to take over the entire conversion process:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<KeyValuePair<DictionaryType, string>, DictionariesListViewModels>()
    .ConvertUsing(r => new DictionariesListViewModels { Type = r.Key, Name = r.Value });
```

**Example:** https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gxhw6A